# Compression packet of Minecraft as3 (ActionScript3)

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, arrays, zlib, minecraft

I'm trying to connect to minecraft server with as3.
The server returns a ByteArray that I am unable to understand.
Here's an example:

```
    «¢00
    *H÷
0[ÞJí"
nöí_Jí2Q»÷/½KW9ó`ä¦ËJ!ôàNÄÇgkÉÚY`*u\êRáåLøjTp9ÔÅڕQ̺ÐWÊýÆ¶[Ð5æsövxåIIÃ¦>Z
u¾C­ӷ.C¹i΍PWûóM×
```

I tried the following to interpret the data:

```
bytes.uncompress();
```

but I got this error:

```
Error: Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data.
```

Comment: It would help our analysis if you could output the string in hexidecimal

Comment: 74:00:72:7b:22:64:65:73:63:72:69:70:74:69:6f:6e:22:3a:22:41:20:4d:69:6e:65:63:72:61:66:74:20:53:65:72:76:65:72:22:2c:22:70:6c:61:79:65:72:73:22:3a:7b:22:6d:61:78:22:3a:32:30:2c:22:6f:6e:6c:69:6e:65:22:3a:30:7d:2c:22:76:65:72:73:69:6f:6e:22:3a:7b:22:6e:61:6d:65:22:3a:22:53:70:69:67:6f:74:20:31:2e:38:22:2c:22:70:72:6f:74:6f:63:6f:6c:22:3a:34:37:7d:7d

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://wiki.vg/Protocol to understand the format of the TCP packets exchanged between a minecraft server and client?

Comment: Write what zlib
But it does not work...

Comment: I haven't looked at the wiki yet, my guess is that the traffic has some binary header that you have to decode before you get to any data that might be compressed.

Comment: Can I have an example please?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Packet_format, the Packet format for Minecraft is as shown below.  You need to interpret the bits of the data that you receive as shown below and then send the compressed data to zlib, if the packet is compressed.

### Packet format

#### Without compression

```
  Field Name   Field Type   Notes
  ------------ ------------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Length       VarInt       Length of packet data + length of the packet ID
  Packet ID    VarInt
  Data         Byte Array   Depends on the connection state and packet ID, see the sections below
```

#### With compression

Once a Set Compression packet is sent,
[zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) compression
is enabled for all following packets. The format of a packet changes
slighty to include the size of the uncompressed packet.

```
  Field Name    Field Type   Notes
  ------------  ------------ -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Packet Length VarInt       Length of Data + length of Data Length
  Data Length   VarInt       Length of uncompressed Data or 0
  Data          Byte Array   zlib compressed packet, including packet ID (see the sections below)
```

How do you know that your packet is compressed?  According to this same documentation, compression isn't enabled until a [Set Compression](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Set_Compression) is sent.

Comment: I do not know how to access the gibberish that I got if its not compressed.